# What am i doing wrong with my express.js hello world and my Docker setup?

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I am attempting to do two things

1. Create a basic "hello world" type app using Node/Express.js.
2. Have that app hosted in docker (on my local system for now, which is
   Mac OS)

This is what I have folder-wise:

```
root of application
-> node_modules
-> .dockerignore
-> Dockerfile
-> index.js
-> package-lock.json
-> package.json
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY package.json /app/
RUN cd /app; npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

My index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8888
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-software",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Software",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

My .dockerignore:

```
node_modules/
```

This is what I am doing to try to get it to run.

1) First I verify that my express app works independantly by running `npm install` and then `node index.js`.  I can see that it runs and is available on a browser at localhost:8888.

2) After running `docker build .` I get something like this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.94kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:lts
 ---> 75a3a4428e1d
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR "/app"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57a5a3028928
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 74939286881b
Step 4/7 : RUN cd /app; npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f7e142ba9040
Step 5/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea7cc365795d
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 8888
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 82297fe77ca8
Step 7/7 : CMD ["node", "index.js"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2fb0c6c00a3
Successfully built e2fb0c6c00a3
```

3) After this i run `docker run e2fb0c6c00a3` (using the hash of whatever was built in step 2)

Note: in the console it sure looks as though it is running. I see a message saying "Example app listening on port 8888!" but when I reload locahost:8888 in the browser i get nothing.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the following [in the Docker documentation for `EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port.
>   ...
>   To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports

So you should use `docker run -p 8888:8888 e2fb0c6c00a3`

Comment: This works for me.  Yea i figured it was something simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your web server on node, which is running in container, from your **host** system, you need to somehow specify valid host name.

The simplest thing ever you can do is to use `host` network mode when starting your docker. Then you would be able to connect with `localhost`:

```
docker run -it --net=host blahblah
```

Otherwise, if you dont specify `host` network, you will need to know `ip address` of your container. And connect to it with this address specified.

Comment: `--net=host` is kind of a hack and it’d be better to set up Docker networking properly.  In particular, it’s important to learn what `localhost` actually means in Docker.  Also you should probably never look up the container’s Docker-internal IP address, there are many subtleties and pitfalls to it an you pretty much never need it.

Comment: I agree, that `--net=host` violates container isolation, no doubt on that. But it is not prohibited and I just wanted to provide quick solution for diving into containerization. Long-term plan, ofc, should include network isolation, container orchestration tools and etc, but `--net=host` is a kind of `hello world` for `docker`

Comment: Upvoting this because while this was not the solution that i'm actually using, i suspect there is useful info in this response.